# Proportionally scaling an image on the left to the height of two lines on the right

Tags: css

I cannot figure out how to scale an image on the left side proportionally to the height of two lines on the right.
I tried to solve the problem with flexbox, but the aspect ratio was not preserved.

```
 <div style="display: flex;">
     <img src="https://www.gnu.org/graphics/heckert_gnu.small.png">
     <div>
         <h1 style="font-size: 128px;">GNU</h1>
         <p style="font-size: 32px;">GNU is Not Unix</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1gh1hr0c/

It seems to involve a circular dependency. The calculation of the width and height of the `img` depend on the height of the right `div`, and the height of the `div` depend on the width of the `div`. The flexbox would need the width of the image to determine the width of the `div`...

Anyway, what I'm trying to do is still quiet a simple in nature. I think there should be a solution using flexbox or something fancy.

Answer (score 0):

use must st property to your flex container `align-items: center;`

```
https://jsfiddle.net/1gh1hr0c/3/
```

Comment: if you don't use align-items all flex-block on the page will be 100% height of the parent

Comment: > if you don't use align-items all flex-block on the page will be 100% height of the parent

That is the expected behavior.
> how to scale an image on the left side proportionally to the height of two lines on the right.